# How to pass function with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I pass function with React Hooks? I've used useCallback, but it shows an error that it is not a function.

In class component I was doing it like this:

```
hidePopUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        popup: !this.state.popup
    })
}
```

Then I was passing function:

```
<Popup hidePopUp={this.hidePopUp}/>
```

That's my problem with Hooks:

```
const hidePopup = useCallback(
    (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setPopup(!popup);
    }, []
);

<Popup hidePopup={() => hidePopup}/>
```

And this is my button in Popup component:

```
<button onClick={(event)=>this.props.hidePopUp(event)}></button>
```

Comment: In your first example, you're setting the `hidePopUp` prop to a function that takes a single argument. In your second example, you're setting the `hidePopUp` prop to a function *that takes no arguments, and returns a function*. Have you tried `<Popup hidePopup={hidePopup} />`?

Comment: You make a mistake in the name of the function. Prop name - `hidePopup`, function name - `hidePopUp`. 'Up' - from the upper case

Comment: 2 silly mistakes, anyway thank you guys, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** of all spelling mistakes and some common mistakes in passing reference to same function. Otherwise it shouldn't be a problem at all passing the memoized version of this function at all.

*Working demo* [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/73lj8jjoj0).

**Second**, there is no actual use of `useCallback` being seen here.

You should use a dependency to update your function to represent correct value of `popup` variable. Here's how:

```
const togglePopUp = useCallback(
    event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setPopup(!popup);
    },
    [popup]
  );
```

Third, when you pass the function as prop, you can pass that directly the reference

```
<Popup hidePopup={togglePopUp}/>
```

**Note** - I've renamed your `hidePopUp` to `togglePopUp`

Comment: Would you be able to change the value of popup in the child component via the passed in function? 
***in childComponent
togglePopUp(true)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use pass the function without using `useCallback()`.
I had the similar issue today. Then I realized that I need to add `const` before the variable which you declared to assign function. Simply, you should add `const` before `hidePopUp()` you created, because you are using arrow function there.

The updated version of your function should be:

```
const hidePopUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        popup: !this.state.popup
    })
}
```

Extra note: I am not saying using `useCallback` is false which other people advised. I want to emphasize that the problem you faced is not about callback.