# How do I pass this data from child to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, parent-child, react-props

I simply want to use a data that has been calculated in a child component and also use the same data in my parent component. How do i do so? This is my current approach, it works but i get this error:

> Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Please suggest a correct method.

Parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");
  const getValue = (value) => {
    setMyValue(value);
  };

  return (
      <div className={styles.innerContainer}>
        <div className={styles.introPara}>{myValue}</div>
        <Child passToParent={getValue} />
      </div>

  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Child

```
const Child = ({ passToParent }) => {
  let url = "www.google.com";
  const findUrl = () => {
    return url;
  };
  let finalValue = findUrl();
  const finalText = finalValue.toUpperCase();

  passToParent(finalText);

  return (
    <div>
      <a href={finalValue}>
        <div>{finalText}</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

I want to use the *finalText* in both Child and Parent components but i don't want to repeat the logic i'm using in finalUrl( ). Currently i'm simply using passToParent( ) and it works but gives error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: Pass `setMyValue` directly as prop to child.

Comment: @im_baby The other question link's answers do not work in my case. I dont want to trigger anything onClick and get that value. I just want to simply pass and use the same value in parent

Comment: Have you tried passing `setMyValue` as the prop instead of `getValue`?

Comment: @im_baby works! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try this - just pass **myValue** - instead **getFunction**:

---

1. **getValue** - this is the function - it's should be triggered on some user actions eg. onClick, onMouseEnter etc.
2. You hold **myValue** in **useState** reactHook - it's type: **string**
3. In child u destructurizing props - so there is option just to write it without processing.
4. [Also there is possibility to pass function to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042725/how-to-pass-function-with-react-hooks/56043077)

---

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");

  const getValue = (value) => {
    setMyValue(value);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <Child passToParent={myValue} />
      </div>

  );
};

export default Parent;
```

---

```
const Child = ({ passToParent }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <a>
        <div>{passToParent}</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Comment: Just by passing myValue wont trigger the getValue() function and it wont setMyValue to the new value

Comment: So pass setMyValue instead - and trigger in child component